# busqueda en archivo Python

Tags: python

'''quiero saber si alguien me puede dar una idea de como arreglar esto, lo que pasa es que la variable dni la escribí antes en el archivo lista_pacientes pero el if me da False'''

```
 while True:
        try:
            dni= int(input("ingrese su dni"))  
            arch=open('lista_pacientes.txt','r')
            if dni in arch:  
                turno= validar_turno()
                escribir_turno(turno,dni)
                print(turno)
                break  
            else:
                raise dato_incorrecto   
        except ValueError:
            print("tipo de dato ingresado incorrecto")
        except dato_incorrecto:
            print("dni equivocado")
        except IOError:
            print("error inesperado...")
    arch.close
    return turno
```

Comment: En primer lugar debes de leer el archivo y en segundo lugar no puedes hacer `dni in arch` si `dni` es un numero

Comment: si a dni le ingreso como input si?, porque la variable din ya la escribí dentro del archivo antes pero ahora pido denuevo el dni para corroborar que este escrito dentro del archivo.

Comment: lo correcto sería hacer `dni in arch.read()` y que `dni` sea un string

Comment: que crack, gracias Christian.

Answer (score 1):

`in`  busca en los elementos de un `iterator`. `arch` no es un iterator pero es iterable, lo que significa que puede crearse un iterator a partir de él con `iter(arch)`. Esto es lo que hace python y lo que produce el iterador en este caso son `str`s con cada linea del archivo.

Entonces se compara dni, que es un `int` con cada linea del archivo que es un `str`, lo que da `False` en todos los casos.

Y aunque fuera `dni` convertido a `str` tampoco funcionaria porque `dni` no sería igual a ninguna linea pues las líneas terminan con un salto de línea '\n' (Ademas que las lineas podrian contener otros datos ademas del dni)

Una opcion es leer todo el archivo en un `str` con arch.read() y entonces si utilizar el 'in'. Eso chequearía que el dni esta en el archivo.

Pero si precisas saber en que linea esta para leer otros campos del registro entonces debes utiliazar e  'in' en cada una de las lineas. Por ejemplo en un bucle `for`

```
for linea in arch:
    if str(dni) in linea:
        #encontrado
        ...
        break
else:
    # no se encuentra      
    ...
```

el bloque `else` se ejecuta solo si nuca se llega a `break`

Comment: me gusto mucho tu idea, muchas gracias. estoy probando también la primera idea del 'in' ,pero si en el archivo estaba escrito dni=10 (en formato str) y busco dentro del archvivo dni=1, me da verdadero aunque no es el mismo, sabes que orcurre?.

Comment: @valentino eso ocurre por que 1 está dentro de 10, es como escribir `"1" in "10"` y eso da `True`

Comment: @valentino claro, el `in` no funciona porque podria darse el caso como tu dices que el dni este incluido en otro. Deberias adecuar el algoritmo a la estructura de cada registro del archivo y extraer el dni completo de cada linea. 

Si la linea pone solo dni=<numero> entonces puedes usar `linea[4:-1]` que remueve la parte 'dni=' y el salto final de linea.